# Save app when user exits using back button

Tags: java, android

I know that when the user presses back button the saveoninstance is not supposed to be called.

I have a layout with many edittexts added dynamically by user, and then the user can enter text. I managed to save these when the user rotates screen using saveoninstance etc.

However, I also want to save these when the user exits app using the back button so when the app is opened again a "continue" button should be available for the user to continue (meaning adding all the text boxes again). I kind of know how to save and retrieve them, but which method should I use? Should i write a file for a example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the user pressed back button application is closed. When he open app again it start as new instance and don't remember what user done before.
If u have to save data, then u can save them (eg. to Preferences or database) in *onPasue* or *onDestroy*

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to save and retrieve them, why dont you just override the Back button and write save functionality there.

e.g.

```
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
    /*Your functione here to what should be done on Back Button Press event*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is, you have override the below method in your Activity,

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

And save the state of your activity in SharedPrefrence, and next time when you enter your Activity get the value from the Sharedpreference and set the state accordingly.

Example,

```
 private void SavePreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("state", "true");
    editor.commit(); 
   }

      private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean  state = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("state", false);
    button.setEnabled(state);
   }

   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SavePreferences();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

    onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   //just a rough sketch of where you should load the data
    LoadPreferences();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically shared preference in android are used to save the state of an activity or to save the important data within the scope of an application means data will remain saved till the application is installed in the devices. Shared Preference also works as Sessions which are used for the automatic login process.

see this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

And here is an [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/664365/Android-SharedPreference).

Answer (score 0):

Well its pretty simple. All you need to do is:

1. Use shared preferences and bundle.
2. Save everything in the `onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState)`

Now how you do is:

1. Overwrite the function `onSavedInstanceStae(Bundle outState)`
   and inside it
2. Save everything in Shared Preferences and then bundle them ,and this bundle is then sent automatically as a parameter in your `onCreate(Bundle bundle)`
3. Thus in your `onCreate` check if the `bundle==null;` if not retrieve sharedPreferences and load the data just like you saved it.